# Clearing the cache (recompile) for a database in sqlserver without restarting it sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to clear all of the cache for a specific database somewhat equivalent to what OPTION(RECOMPILE) does for a stored proc?

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing is:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

More on: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)

Look at remarks section closely:

> Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache
>   without shutting down and restarting the server. To drop clean buffers
>   from the buffer pool, first use CHECKPOINT to produce a cold buffer
>   cache. This forces all dirty pages for the current database to be
>   written to disk and cleans the buffers. After you do this, you can
>   issue DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to remove all buffers from the
>   buffer pool.

You will usually use this:

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

What cache are you talking about?

If Procedure Cache you can use [`DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB(<db_id>);`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/05/21/clearing-plans-for-a-single-database.aspx)

If all caches, including procedure cache and buffer cache, you can use

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET OFFLINE --WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET ONLINE
```